# Polar to Cartesian: r = 3 + sin(theta/2)

Tags: functions, polar-coordinates

I am asked to convert the following polar function to cartesian:
$$r = 3 + sin(\theta/2)$$

I would be able to do it if it weren't for the fraction.

I have already tried substituting the identity $sin(\theta/2) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{1 - cos(x)}{2}}$ but that is a dead end as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I have tried the identity of sin(theta/2) but that seems to be a dead end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2(r-3)^2=1-\cos\theta$

$2r^2-12r-17=-\dfrac xr$

$x=r\{17+ 12r-2(x^2+y^2)\}$

$x-12(x^2+y^2)=r(17-2x^2-2y^2)$

Now square both sides

Comment: I think you might have dropped the - on the 12r^2

Comment: @Marcel, $$12r^2=12(x^2+y^2)$$ is in the Left hand side in the last line

Comment: @yesterday  from line 2 to line 3 2r^2 and 17 change signest but 12 doesn't.

Comment: @Marcel, Thanks for your observation